# Minecraft: Super Secret Settings Black Screen

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, graphics-card

So, it's come to my attention that whenever I press "Super Secret Settings" in the options menu, Minecraft goes black. I can click buttons, and stuff like that, but I can't see. I just restart the game, and it's fine. I've looked at a few little threads (including [the official bug post](https://bugs.mojang.com/browse/MC-32663)), and determined that it's not an OS incompatibility issue, but Intel HD Integrated Graphics. I don't mind having to restart the game, but I do like some of the super secret settings visual effects. I really don't care what is causing this (although I suspect it's because of some kind of shader bug), and I just want to get it fixed.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Hold the Windows key, and press R. When the run box opens, just type in `%appdata%`, and your roaming folder will open. Then, in the search bar, type in options.txt, and wait for the search to stop loading. Open the first result, a text file named "options" with notepad and search for "fast render" or, you find can it with CTRL+F. It will read `Fast Render = On`. Change on to off, press CTRL+S, start Minecraft, (unless it is already open, in which case, restart it) and your hitherence shalt be resolved.

Comment: And where, exactly, is that setting?

Comment: Just go to %appdata%/.Minecraft and search Options.txt.

Comment: The point is, you should be adding that information to your answer.

Comment: Fast Rendering includes some options that improve performance, in exchange for lower quality. AFAIK it's not the ones for leaves, but rather all that stuff that OptiFine seemingly adds in, water and grass and stuff like that. Or maybe Im mixing it up with something entirely different. Anyways, it's something that would need different shaders for super secret settings, so probably those are missing, such that Fast Rendering and Super Secret Settings become incompatible.

Answer (score -2):

You are most likely missing the shader files in your .minecraft folder. Super secret settings are basically vanilla minecraft shaders and sometimes can be deleted through updates or installing mods.